# K-Mean Clustering: Evaluating new Cluster centers

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, data-analysis

Is it better to evaluate new Cluster centers after each iteration of all data points, or after assigning a cluster to each data point? To clarify, which of the two methods is preferred:

1. You assign all the data points to various clusters and then find the new cluster center
2. Or, you assign the next data point to the nearest cluster and find the new Cluster center, move on to the next point as repeat...

Answer (score 3):

These are more or less two main approaches

1. It is more or less Lloyd approach - you iterate over all datapoints, assign each to the nearest cluster, then move all centers accordingly, repeat.
2. It is more or less a Hartigan approach - you iterate over each data point and look if it is better to move it to other cluster (does it minimize the energy/make cluster more "dense"), repeat until no possible changes.

Which of the two is better? Empirical studies shows multiple advantages of Hartigan approach. In particular one can prove, that Hartigan will not work worse than Lloyd (each Hartigan optima is also a Lloyd optima, but not the other way around). There is a nice theoretical and practical analysis in http://ijcai.org/papers13/Papers/IJCAI13-249.pdf showing, that one should follow second approach, especially if there are many, potentially irrelevant features in the data.

Comment: But if you suggest Hartigan approach to be better, wouldn't this cause an issue with obtaining  a local optima very early in the process, thus causing more number of iterations to reach the global optima. For instance, lets say the very first data point you consider is the furthest in the final cluster you obtain, thus making the very first cluster center update very inaccurate. But if you follow Lloyd's approach, wouldn't the first update always be at least as accurate as Hartigan's. Not stating as a fact, but just wondering...

Comment: Every method has a counterexample, this is not the point. Take a look at the tests, in general - lloyd performs worse, this is just an empirical conclusion, not a theoretical result :)

Comment: lejlot you seems like have great experience with clustering can you check this question if you have time : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404742/how-to-calculate-clustering-success-pre-assigment-true-classes-are-known ty